# How can i change colors in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, colors

So i searched for it and i found many answers. I found that in c++ there's no standard cross-platform way to do that and that the operative system manages colors. For example i found that on windows you can use the system("color 1") statement to change color to the text ( or foreground) and the system("color A") to change color to the background, or both system("color 1A") to change both. But this will change the whole colors, and i was wondering if there was a way to change it like even for a single character. Like take the program that i just did as an example:

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;  /* I prefer to use this because i think that's a huge time saver and it's also easier*/

void printRoad(int i)  /* That's my function, so by this function it prints a number of times choosed by the user 4 pieces of road*/
{
    int counter=1;
    while (counter <= i)
    {
        system("color 2");           /*Here is what i was talking about. I used the system("color 2") statement to change the text color
                                     from the default to green, but it changes the whole text.*/
        cout << "** | **" << endl;
        cout << "** | **" << endl;
        cout << "** | **" << endl;
        cout << "** | **" << endl;
        counter++;
    }
};
void main()  /*I don't need any specific return value from either the main() and the function so i thought it was a good idea to
             just use void.*/
{
    cout << "How many piece of roads do you want to build?" << endl;  /*Here it asks to the user what to do.*/
    int pieces = 0;
    cin >> pieces;
    printRoad(pieces);   //Here is the function call.


    system("pause");     /* Because i'm using windows and i'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 I used system("pause") to pause 
                         the program and let the user see the output.*/
}
```

So what if, for example, i'd like to change each piece of road color? Like the first cout<<"** | **"<

I also read many people complaining about the use of system("") statements. I understand it because by doing so your program lose the cross-platform ability. But if the thing is dependent on the system we're on, how should we do it by keeping the cross-platform ability? Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use this instead of calling ***system()***:

> SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ValueOfColour);

As far as I understood your problem, you only want a certain character to be in your choosen colour. Then you need to change it back to the default value white/grey after this character was printed.

Comment: Yes that's my intention. I really like these type of statements because they're the same that are used in Unreal Engine 4, but i don't understand all of them. If you can explain it this is exactly what i was looking for thank you very much.

Comment: Well, actually this method is pretty simple. `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` requires two parameters. The first is a handle to the output in the console. You can get this one by using `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` which returns a handle to the output. The second parameter is the value of your colour which the output should be in. The type of it is a integer for example. If you changed the colour once and you want the next output stream to be in default colour, you need to change it back then. I hope this could help you.

Comment: Since there is no default color you can return to, [WriteConsoleOutputAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687407.aspx) might be a better match, given the specification. It doesn't modify text and background colors beyond the text that was written.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I think you can go this way with the default colour because usually it is grey in console.

Comment: Console colors are configurable per-user. On my system, the colors for the admin console do not have the default colors. I'd be pretty irritated, if it changed to something I did not ask for.